# How to fix TextMate error: env: ruby18: Permission denied

Tags: textmate

I'm using TextMate and every time I tried to use a shortcut `cmd + /` to comment a line, I get the following message: `env: ruby18: Permission denied` with an option to either edit the comment of dismiss it. How can I fix that?

Comment: did you find a solution?